# How to install pycrypto in pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

I want to use "from Crypto.Cipher import AES" in pycahrm for running the AES encryption and decryption code. But when I want to install pycrypto or pycryptodome, the terminal shows this message:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6gk6aq_f\pycryptodome
```

How can I install these packages?

Comment: try to install globally using terminal
`pip install pycryptodome`

Comment: @Deven Ramani, I use this command but has the error

Comment: are you using venv (virtual python environment)?

Comment: @Deven Ramani, Yes.

Comment: then you need to activate that venv and then `pip install pycryptodome`

Comment: @Deven Ramani, Can I ask what's your mean? I can install other packages like crypto with this but when I run pip install pycryptodome it shows an error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there's a problem in the version of pycrypto/pycryptodome that you're installing. The lines prior to the one in your question should contain details about what this is. It could be that this distribution doesn't work on windows, doesn't specify all the dependencies it needs or one of many other problems. If you can post the entire error we should be able to give more advice.

You could try installing an early version to see if that works, the current version of pycryptodome is 3.10.1 so try `pip install pycryptodome==3.9.9` which is the previous version in PyPI.

Another thing you can do is install the distribution a different way. Try [downloading the .tar.gz archive of the package](https://pypi.org/project/pycryptodome/3.10.1/#files) and pip installing that file e.g. `pip install pycryptodome-3.10.1.tar.gz`

Both of these solutions may work but it's impossible to say without knowing the precise problem with the install.

---

On pycrypto [github](https://github.com/pycrypto/pycrypto/issues) there seem to be a lot of installation problems and the recommendation is) to use pycryptodome instead.

Comment: @D Hudson, Thank you for your help. I changed the version of pycharm and after that the packages installed.

Answer (score 1):

Pycharm -> Preference -> Project -> Python Interpreter -> + pycryptodome.
Since pycrypto hasn't maintained for years, install **pycryptodome** instead.

[image]

Comment: Where can I find the Preferences -> Project menu? I can't see that anywhere in pyCharm Professional (Windows) menus. I tried "Shift + Shift" -> Settings: Python Interpreter, did you mean that? In my case `pycryptodome` was already showing up there, I (re-)installed it using this menu, and then the import statement worked!

Comment: Another hint can be found here: [why-do-i-get-the-error-no-module-named-crypto-on-windows](https://www.pycryptodome.org/src/faq#why-do-i-get-the-error-no-module-named-crypto-on-windows): In my case, that resolved the issue.